# Help with derivation of Kinetic Energy of N point masses

Tags: energy, rotational-kinematics

There are $N$ point masses as shown in image each with mass $m_i$ and velocity $v_i$.
[image]

We need to find the Kinetic Energy of the system. Here is the proof attached I have some doubt in it.
[image]

The doubt starts in 3rd last line. How do they factorize it? How do $\omega^T$ and $\omega$ come out given that $\omega$ and $p$ are 3x1 vectors? Basically, how do dimensions play out. It is taken from the book "Introduction to feedback control using design studies by Randal W. Beard" 2nd chapter Page-14. Book can be found at the link - http://controlbook.byu.edu/doku.php#introduction_to_feedback_controlusing_design_studies .

Comment: Matrix multiplication is still distributive. You can try plugging in numbers to verify that it holds.

Comment: @ConnorBehan In the 3rd last line $\omega^T$ is 1x3 and $p^T$ is 1x3. So, how do they multiply?

Comment: Oh that's what you mean. The parentheses were kept because $(p^T p) I_3$ is a scalar times the identity matrix.